# Bootstrap 3 input Date format

Tags: date, twitter-bootstrap-3, format

I would like to know without using any plugin/library, is it possible to format bootstrap date input format.
My webservice will return ISO.DATE pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", and bootstrap displays it in MM/DD/YYYY format. I want to change it to DD/MM/YYYY  format.

Is it possible to do ?  I googled and every one seem to be using some library. Since my requirement is simple, I do not want to use any library.  Or do you think a library is required.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for=displayFrom class="col-md-3 control-label"> Date </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <form:input type="date" class="form-control" path="displayFrom" id="displayFrom"
                        placeholder="display From"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 iserror">
        <form:errors path="displayFrom"></form:errors>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Misunderstood, thought you are using HTML5 datepicker, not jquery datepicker.... Check my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain ? some tags like 'path ' are used by my server to render the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using HTML5's date input which uses the YYYY-MM-DD format, which is unchangeable right now. Chrome and Opera uses the local computer's locale to set the format of the input, Firefox and IE uses the default YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: "without using any plugin/library,"

Comment: @TheLittlePig Man, bootstrap 3 is using a custom datetimepicker, THAT'S A PLUGIN can't do it without it .....

Comment: @TheLittlePig He tagged bootstrap-3 not HTML5 so that's why i think that the OP is using the jquery based datetimepicker.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not work. I am new to client scripting, If you don't mind can you put a jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok i created one, can you please take a look at  it ? http://plnkr.co/edit/xQwgLhhQ1UZXToauajrb

Comment: @Mukun You can't change HTML5's date input's format. It is based on the local computer (the visitor) in Chrome and Opera, Firefox and IE is using the default format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @newboyhun Correct me if I am wrong... Bootstrap 3 is using HTML 5 date, so support of HTML 5 date depends on browser as per your answer. If I need support for all browser, then I have to use library ?

Comment: @Mukun Bootstrap 3 doesn't have any datepicker, so basically it doesn't use any datepicker, you are correct, you have to download a datepicker, like: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Firefox now uses a date based on the user's locale.